From matplotlib to latex. Good idea to change the mathematical expressions?
I have a question regarding matplotlib and latex. What I am doing is to create a plot in matplotlib and export it as pgf. This is an example:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate some data
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

# Configure Matplotlib to use LaTeX
plt.rcParams.update({
    "text.usetex": True,
    "pgf.texsystem": "pdflatex",
    "font.family": "serif",
    "font.size": 10,
    "pgf.preamble": r"\usepackage{amsmath}"
})

# Create the plot
plt.figure(figsize=(4, 3))
plt.plot(x, y, label=r"$\sin(x)$")
plt.title(r"Example Plot: $\sin(x)$")
plt.xlabel(r"$x$")
plt.ylabel(r"$\sin(x)$")
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()

# Export to PGF
plt.savefig("example_plot.pgf")

Now I have defined in my latex file some macros like x is \gls{xcoordinate}.
I want to replace all the x's in my created .pgf-file with \gls{xcoordinate}.
Is this possible with regular expressions for example? Is there another, better way to reach my goal?

Not sure I follow correctly. But since you are already using tex macros, why not continue to rely on macro mechanism for that? I would \def\x{\gls{xcoordinate}} both in your preamble and your latex file (preferably using a common source to include in both).

Btw, as is, your preamble has no effect. You miss the matplotlib.use("pgf") line
